# Python: Do we really need wrappers for decorators? (Revisited)

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335580/why-do-we-need-wrapper-function-in-decorators) has been asked, but the OP compares the wrapper to a function without return, thus the answers focus on that "fault".
I understood decorators and why we use them instead of sub-classes after reading [this article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/decorators-python). There, they write the following example in which they introduce the need of the wrapper:

```
def uppercase_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        funct = function()
        make_uppercase = funct.upper()
        return make_uppercase

    return wrapper
```

Yet, I can write "the same thing" (I'm expecting you to say it is not), this way:

```
def uppercase_decorator(function): #previously 'function' was called 'message' but 'function' is clearer for comparison. 
    make_uppercase = function().upper
    return make_uppercase
```

Both versions could be applied to this fn, resulting in the same output ('HI ALL!') when calling `salute()`:

```
@uppercase_decorator
def salute():
    return 'Hi all!'
```

If main fn returns a random string (thanks to @wim for suggestion) one can notice that every time it runs it, the one without wrapper always returns the same thing when running the `sayGarbage()` line:

```
def decorateIt(fn):
    toUpper = fn().upper  
    return toUpper  

def decorateW(fn):  
    def wrapper():  
        funct = fn()  
        toUpper = funct.upper()  
        return toUpper  
    return wrapper  

import random, string  

@decorateIt  
def sayGarbage():  
    return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(6))  

sayGarbage()
```

Why is that so?

Comment: What is `message` in your version of `uppercase_decorator` doing? Where did `func()` come from?

Comment: Totally misunderstanding how decorators work.  The decorator *receives the to-be-decorated function* as argument!

Comment: The difference is that the second version *does not work*.

Comment: Sorry, I missed changing 'funct' to 'message'. Now it should work

Comment: Now it "works" because you have two mistakes that cancel eachother out  :)

Comment: Oh, really? (ashamed...)

Comment: After the decoration, salute will now be the *method* `'Hi all!'.upper`.

Comment: Do you mean this is what happens with a well defined decorator? Or do you mean that this is what is happening in my case but it shouldn't be that way? (I changed 'message' to 'function' to reflect what I think it is doing)

Comment: Oh, you mean, salute will be "just" the method, and we want to extend the functionality, not to restrict it...

Answer (score 4):

Let's look what happens here:

```
def uppercase_decorator(message): 
    make_uppercase = func().upper
    return make_uppercase

@uppercase_decorator
def salute():
    return 'Hi all!'
```

- Firstly, `uppercase_decorator` gets defined.
- Secondly, `salute` gets defined.
- Thirdly, `uppercase_decorator` gets *called*, passing in the function object `salute` in the place of the first positional argument (`message`).

At this point, the code will crash, because `func()` gets called and that was not defined anywhere.  If it worked in your Python REPL session, then you must have had the name `func` lying around in global scope from earlier, and so the code only appeared to work by coincidence.

> Do we really need wrappers for decorators?

No. It is possible to write decorators in a nicer "closureless" style like you suggest.  To write a decorator without the nested function, you can use the popular library [`decorator.py`](https://github.com/micheles/decorator).  It works like this:

```
from decorator import decorator

@decorator
def uppercase_decorator(func, *args, **kwargs):
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return result.upper()
```

Comment: No, I thought I had seen the difference after your comment above saying that salute will now be the method `'Hi all!'.upper`, but the wrapper version would do the same as I see it. Why would assigning `function()` to an intermediate variable (`funct`), make any difference?

Comment: Consider what happens at decoration time. In your first version, the function is *used* but it is not actually being *called*. In the second version, your function actually gets called. Perhaps, instead of `return 'Hi all!'` you should return a randomly generated string, something which will be different each time instead of just a constant value - that will show you the difference in behavior between the two versions more clearly.

Comment: I've made it to return a random string and created two decorator (with and without wrapper). Both versions return a different uppercase string each time. Failed to notice any difference... (!?) : I'm updating the code in the question as I can't format it properly here...

Comment: Your example is good - using your `decorateIt`, this returns the _same_ random string everytime. Using `decorateW` returns a different random string everytime. I'm not sure how/why you would see anything different, probably some PEBKAC here.

Comment: I was just running the whole code, instead of just the fn call, that's why... Now I see what you say. I also see the problem doesn't have anything to do with the intermediate variable, which is not actually needed, but only with not having the wrapper. Having it or not is what makes the code working or returning a `'str' object is not callable` exception.. So thanks for your tip, I still need to see the iceberg but, although slow, I'm getting closer to see it...

Comment: It used to return the same string, but I 'fixed' it and now it returns the mentioned exception. I'm tired and can't remember what I did 'to fix it' (it was clearly a progress though). Yet I understand that `sayGarbage()` doesn't just run the decorated function; the @decorator substitutes `sayGarbage()` for `decorator= decorateIt(sayGarbage)` and then calls `decorator()`. My mind is not clear now but I have a blurred intuition that this is what makes `sayGargage()` return 'str is not callable'. The wrapper manages to not return the result of the decorator function but a fn object, without '()'