# Why does a decorator needs a wrapper

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

I've read all the answers to both these two questions:
[Why do we need wrapper function in decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335580/why-do-we-need-wrapper-function-in-decorators/57017013#57017013) and [Why are decorator functions designed in the way they are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544319/why-are-decorator-functions-designed-in-the-way-they-are), but I still don't get it.

Why is a decorator written as such:

```
def decorator_function(function):
    def wrapper_function():
        print('Before the decoration')
        function()
        print('After the decoration')
    return wrapper_function
```

Rather than just like this:

```
def decorator_function(function):
    print('Before the decoration')
    function()
    print('After the decoration')
    return function
```

And why is is that when I do this:

```
@decorator_function
def original_function():
    print('Original function')
```

In the first case, with the wrapper function, if I call the function like this `original_function()` the return is:

```
Before the decoration
Original function
After the decoration
```

But in the second case, without the wrapper function, if I call the function, this is the result instead:

```
Before the decoration
Original function
After the decoration
Original function
```

The original function gets called one more time

Why do I need the wrapper function?

Comment: Because the decorator returns a function object. You can decorate other things than functions.

Comment: @JohnColeman Really? Even if OP claims they read it and didn't get it?

Comment: Voting to close the question as a duplicate. The fact that you didn't understand the answer in the duplicate doesn't change its status as a duplicate. If you want to ask a new question, there needs to be something about the question which distinguished it from the other.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I don't understand your issue. If OP wants to clarify what it is that they don't understand, then they could ask a new question, but duplicates are still duplicates. If you feel that duplicates shouldn't be closed in situations like this, perhaps you could raise the issue on [meta].

Comment: Agreed. Stack Overflow requires *specific* questions. "I didn't understand this, can you explain it again?" isn't something that can be answered in Stack Overflow's format, because a) it isn't clear *why* OP doesn't understand and b) even if it were clear, it doesn't lead to *a question that can provide a good search engine result for others*. This is *not a discussion forum*. I would note there is *a* specific question here ("why does this code snippet have the behaviour that it does?"), but the question is answered by simply tracing through the logic of the code.

Comment: OP: if you need help tracing through the logic, see the [long answer second from the top here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together), and take some time to study.